# How to send an array to a function as an address

Tags: c, arrays, function

So basically I want to send a array to a function and basically create a 2d array.

I have this:

```
int col,row;
Item array[row][col];
```

I'm sending it to a function like this:

```
create(row,col, array)
```

and the actual function takes in like this

```
void create(int row, int col, Item array[row][col)
```

When I do this, my program complies but doesn't output the correct answer.

How do I send it like an address, so it can create the 2d array and then I can use it in the main function.

Comment: If the program compiles but does not output the correct answer then it means that it has nothing common with how to pass an array to a function.:) You already created a variable length array. What do you want else?

Comment: You might have made some typos in asking the question, but I don't think this would compile.  Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it works if I print like the array inside the function but I print the array in the main function. Also, if I put what I have inside the function to the main function, it works perfectly.

Comment: Syntax error here:  void create(int row, int col, Item array[row][col)   (missing a ])

Comment: @KevinJones The main and the second function deal with the same array. So you are doing something wrong in the function. Show the function.

Comment: How have you initialized `row` and `col` before you declare the array using them as sizes?  Your code isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]) and doesn't show that rather important detail.  Or, if that part is complete and accurate, then you've no idea how big the array is going to be.

Comment: I'm sure it was a typo, but I agree we can't figure this out without seeing more code.

Comment: that was a typo, but the way I'm doing is the correct way to pass it?

Comment: Yes, your code would be correct if syntax-corrected and if your initialization of `row` and `col` is sensible.  But you've not shown enough code for anyone to be able to pontificate.

Comment: I get the row and col from a file, using fgets and scan, i didn't get put it in my code but I also send char File[] into the function.

Comment: Show us the code!  We shouldn't have to guess what you're doing — you should show us what you're doing so we can help you understand what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an array function first:

```
void array (int col, int row, int d[col][row])
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
  d[i][j] = 0;
 }
```

After that you can passing value  another function

```
void create(void)
 {
  int d1[11][12];
  int d2[13][14];
  array(11, 12, d1);
  array(13, 14, d2);
 }
```